# How do I return the oldest time from SQL for records with same user_id

Tags: mysql, sql

```
user_id     action_time
7595        2017-01-09 19:10:56
7595        2017-01-09 19:13:42
32664727    2017-01-08 12:27:00
32664727    2017-01-08 12:26:30
29714095    2017-01-12 23:03:34
22380075    2017-01-12 18:59:29
22380075    2017-01-12 18:59:59
32670641    2017-01-14 7:45:53
32670641    2017-01-14 7:27:39
23989699    2017-01-12 0:16:28
```

Hi, I have a few records like this, same user_id might have different action times. How can I use SQL to return only the oldest action time for each user_id?

FYI
user_id : bigint
action_time : varchar

Thanks

Comment: Is this data set properly representative of the problem?

Comment: And store dates and times using an appropriate data type

Answer (score 2):

Use mysql aggregation functions. specifically [MIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_min)

> MIN([DISTINCT] expr) Returns the minimum value of expr. MIN() may take a string argument;
>   in such cases, it returns the minimum string value

```
SELECT MIN(action_time), user_id from my_table GROUP BY user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`select t1.* from tablename t1 inner join (select  min(action_time) as mtime from tablename group by user_id) t2 on t1.action_time = t2.mtime;`

Answer (score 0):

Perform a aggregate function on Datetime. here you were looking for oldest date which is a minimum date (16/1/2017 < 17/1/2017). so use Min() function

select userid, min(action_time) from table1 group by userid;

We are grouping because we need only one value per userid.

Answer (score 0):

below code is tested and will give the desired result.

```
select *,min(action_time) from table group by userid;
```